# Movie in which an alien family visit Earth and are serial killers

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

They bleed blue blood and the daughter ends up with an African American guy.

Comment: This question is very terse and could be improved by by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, was this a comedy/horror/action film? Why were the aliens on Earth? How did they get here? What were their names? How were they fitting in? Why were they killing people? What members of the family were there (e.g. mom/dad/kids, etc) and what were their ages? Was this an adult film (with gore/sex) or something aimed at a younger audience? Was this live-action or animated?

Answer (score 7):

That could be [**Alien Avengers**](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115503/?ref_=tt_urv), [YouTube trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6OzezkCzoI)

**Plot**

> Charlie and Rhonda are a sweet and comfortable married couple on
> vacation **with their lovely daughter Daphne**. They find a rundown
> boarding house and its haggard owner, Joseph, an ex-con whose mother
> has just died and left him the house. He doesn't know why this
> cheerful couple would want to vacation in the worst part of Los
> Angeles, but he doesn't know **they're vacationing from outer space**, and
> their idea of fun **is murdering lowlife out on the streets**.

"Aliens":
[image]

Their daughter:
[image]

And her boyfriend:
[image]

Some criminals:
[image]

Wound with the blue blood:
[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Good work. Did you know it or did you search it out?

Comment: @Valorum search: "alien family visit earth daughter"